# Как работать с DataGridComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Просто привязавшись к `DataGrid` создается вот такой контрол:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RecordVms}"
          Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}"
          RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyleStateGreen}">
```

Как написать `DataGridComboBox` чтобы он выглядел точно также и к нему можно было привязываться? Или можно как-то посмотреть какой код сгенерировался в `xaml`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding }">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" " Binding="{Binding }"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" " Binding="{Binding }"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header=" " ItemsSource="{Binding }"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header=" " Binding="{Binding }"/>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

2. Для просмотра сгенерированного кода xaml можно воспользоваться программой  [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).

   [Пример использования](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8EdRR0Tc1k)